# transferFrom is not displaying DAI amount on MetaMask verification popup

Tags: web3js, erc-20, metamask, dai, transferfrom

I am using web3.min_1.36.js to send DAI to a contract. I already called "approve", so transferFrom is working correctly without error.

However, the Metamask verification popup does not display the DAI amount that will be transferred. It just shows "CONTRACT INTERACTION", and the gas fee.

This will confuse users of my app, because they will not know what DAI amount they are verifying.

**How do I force the Metamask verification popup to show the DAI amount that will be transferred?**

Here is the code that performs transferFrom:

```
var objOption = {from: gsMyEtherAddress};
var objContract = new gobjWeb3_metamask.eth.Contract(gsABI_ERC20, gsDaiContractAddress);

objContract.methods.transferFrom(
    gsMyEtherAddress, gsMyContractAddress, gobjWeb3_metamask.utils.toWei((.3).toString(), 'ether')
).send(objOption, async function(error,result){
    if (!error) {
        console.log(result)
    } else {
        alert("Error: " + error.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible. MetaMask doesn't allow apps to change its UI dialogs. It seems a good suggestion for MetaMask developers to show more details about internal transactions.